# Streaming archive stream from node.js in multi-part file post upload

Tags: node.js, asp.net-core

I'm currently working on an application with an Electron front-end and ASP.NET Core backend. The Electron app needs to zip a series of files into an archive and upload the zip to the backend. I am using [archiver](https://archiverjs.com/docs/) to create a zip archive. I can accomplish what I need by outputting the archive to a file, and then opening a read stream of the file and doing the upload.

My goal is to avoiding writing this file temporarily to the file system and uploading the stream directly. I may be completely off base here, but here is my existing code:

```
const archiver = require('archiver');
const str = require('stream');
const request = require('request');

// . . .

const archive = archiver('zip', {
    zlib: { level: 1 } // Set the compression level.
});

// . . . Add files to archive

archive.finalize();

request.post(/* upload url */, {
    formData: {
        // Set additional form properties
        file: {
            options: {
                fileName: "test.zip"
            },
            value: archive
        }
    }
}, function(err, res, body) {
    // Handle response
});
```

I receive the request as expected, but after reading ~50 bytes, asp throws `System.IO.IOException: Unexpected end of Stream`.

What is the correct way to deal with this stream?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the answer is pretty simple. My code works on both ends, however, my stream is of unknown length, and therefore the header `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` is required in order to denote to ASP.NET that the stream is of unknown length. Simply adding this header to the request resolves the issue:

```
request.post(/* upload url */, {
    headers: {
        "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked" // This is all that was needed.
    },
    formData: {
        // Set additional form properties
        file: {
            options: {
                fileName: "test.zip"
            },
            value: archive
        }
    }
}, function(err, res, body) {
    // Handle response
});
```